# What does 'Tag' of union and structure do?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
union Data
{
   int i;
   float f;
   char  str[20];
} data;

structure Data
{
   int i;
   float f;
   char  str[20];
} data;
```

Here, as I know,"data" is a tag and it is optional. What exactly is it? What advantages can I get by adding a tag while declaring a structure or a union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here, as I know,"data" is a tag and it is optional.

No, there is no tag here.  A tag indicates which interpretation of a union is correct.  For example, if your code assigns `data.f` and passes data to another function and it reads `data.str` then you'll have a massive failure in your program that is likely to crash it.  The union itself doesn't give the function enough information to know which union member to use.

By adding a tag, you can indicate which interpretation is correct.  For example:

```
struct TaggedData
{
    int type;
    union Data value;
} taggeddata;
```

Where *type* is the tag and indicates what kind of value is stored in the union.  A function that reads `taggeddata` can now use a `switch` statement and access the correct union member.

Another common name for a tagged data structure is a [variant type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type).  Compare to [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html).